# How do I get these buttons inline?

Tags: html, css, share-button

I'm struggeling a bit with the sharebuttons for social media (Twitter, Facebook, Google+) because the facebook button is a few pixels more down than the other two.
I have the feeling I tried everything in my knowledge, by adding or removing divs, margin, padding etc.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="sharebuttons">
  <div class="sharebutton"><div class="fb-share-button " data-layout="button" data-mobile-iframe="false"></div></div>
  <div class="sharebutton"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a></div>
  <div class="sharebutton"><div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="none"></div></div>
</div>
```

And the only CSS code from my part:

```
.sharebutton{
    display:inline; 
}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Comment: you have a nested div there causing havoc. you should be able to remove that `.fb-share-button` and place the attributes into its parent instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add just float:left and some width looking for your site:

```
.sharebutton {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width:auto;
}
```

Comment: `display: inline-block` and `width: auto` are completely superfluous if you float the element.

Comment: Strange answer.. float and inline-block when you can use one, why two?

Answer (score 4):

You need to vertically align them. Since text is on top I suggest apply this css:

```
.sharebutton {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

this way all buttons will flow to bottom of line and align properly keeping text on top.

Comment: This didn't work for me in this case, I don't know why :/ but thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
.sharebutton {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top; // or bottom as per your needs
}
```